# Inappropriate ioctl for device SIOCGIWRANGE with Atheros in CentOS8

Tags: ioctl, centos8

I am trying to get the list of frequencies of a wireless extension using iwlib but the function `iw_get_range_info` returns -1:

```
if((m_skfd = iw_sockets_open()) < 0)
{
  printf("Error while opening socket.");
  return;
}
if(iw_get_range_info(m_skfd, m_ifname, &m_range) < 0)
{
  printf("No frequency information.");
  return;
}
```

in `iwlib.c`, I see that the function that is being called is `iw_get_ext(skfd, ifname, SIOCGIWRANGE, &wrq)` so I modified this function in `iwlib.h` to get error code:

```
static inline int
iw_get_ext(int          skfd,       /* Socket to the kernel */
       const char *     ifname,     /* Device name */
       int          request,    /* WE ID */
       struct iwreq *   pwrq)       /* Fixed part of the request */
{
  /* Set device name */
  strncpy(pwrq->ifr_name, ifname, IFNAMSIZ);
  /* Do the request */
  int result = ioctl(skfd, request, pwrq);
  if (result < 0)
  {
    printf("ioctl failed and returned errno %s \n",strerror(errno));
  }
  return(result);
}
```

The error that is returned is "Inappropriate ioctl for device" (error 0x19). So ioctl is failing.

The wireless extensions uses the chipset Qualcomm Atheros QCA9890. Driver version is 10.2.4.70.9-2 (but same issue with 10.2.4-1.0-00045).

Except for this, I am able to use the extension normally and to perform AP scans.

**The important thing to note is that the same code with the same hardware is working fine with Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.15.0-118-generic) but not CentOS 8 (kernel 4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64).**

Also, the command `dmesg | grep ath` returns:

```
[    2.013673] systemd[1]: Started Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon.
[   10.052991] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   10.231675] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: qca988x hw2.0 target 0x4100016c chip_id 0x043202ff sub 0000:0000
[   10.233800] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   10.236144] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: firmware ver 10.2.4.70.9-2 api 5 features no-p2p,raw-mode crc32 b8d50af5
[   10.287676] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 bebc7c08
[   11.501908] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[   11.523523] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0: htt-ver 2.1 wmi-op 5 htt-op 2 cal otp max-sta 128 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   11.597526] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x0
[   11.597529] ath: EEPROM indicates default country code should be used
[   11.597530] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   11.597532] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[   11.597533] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[   11.597534] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[   11.644556] ath10k_pci 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having this issue because you're using Wireless extension, which is the old way of communicating with a wireless device. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25979504/2312653) for more details.